# How do I get a memory dump for a specific Azure Web App instance?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App running under an App Service Plan which is set to scale out.

I apply load and it scales to multiple instances, but one of those instances has entered a deadlock situation and stops responding.

I want to be about to take a full memory dump of the specific instance that has deadlocked.

I am able to take a full dump of the web app process via .scm.azurewebsites.net/ProcessExplorer/ but the process I am seeing here has almost no threads so it is clear to me that I am not looking at the process that is deadlocked.

Can I get a memory dump from a specific web app instance under a plan?

Thanks in advance to everyone,
Chris

Answer (score 3):

You can get the list of instance IDs using https://resources.azure.com/. Find your Web App, and go under Instances.

Once you know the Instance ID, you can set the `ARRAffinity` cookie to it when you go to the scm site, and you will hit the instance of your choice (e.g. I use this [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en)). If you're not sure which one it is, you may need to try them all.

Related info in [this post](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/03/access-specific-instance/).

Answer (score 2):

1. Visit [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com)
2. Choose your Azure Web App
3. Choose **Diagnostics as a Service** in the Azure Web App menu
4. Check Memory Dump and check all the instance names
5. Click on the Run button and wait for generating

[image: Memory Dumps]